# How to perform simple percentage calculations with a button in C#?

Tags: c#, math, percentage

I need to calculate how much a salesman gets from a sale, I've tried using the code

```
    private void btnCalculateComission_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        double comission = double.Parse(txtComission.Text);
        double value = double.Parse(txtValue.Text);
        double percentage = 0.1;

        comission = value * percentage;
    }
```

but I still get the error "Input string was not in a correct format."

Any thoughts on what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: As the error says, string either in `txtComission.Text` or `txtValue.Text` is not in correct format.

Comment: Perhaps a dot/comma issue against localization...

Comment: Make sure you test the contents of the text boxes aren't empty strings before you perform any calculations.

Comment: Have you tried to search the error? It's not so rare.

Comment: @L.B Hmm, I don't know, because I want the result to be displayed in `txtComission.Text` and all I typed in `txtVale.Text` is a random number.

Comment: @IanGermann: In my answer I display the calculated value for `comission` in `txtComission.Text`

Comment: The name, `commission`, makes it sound like you are working with money, which means you should avoid floating-point numbers and instead use the `decimal` type.

Comment: Not a direct answer, but look at using [`double.TryParse()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.double.tryparse%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). This will prevent runtime errors by returning a bool indicating success of the parse attempt (and the result in an `out` variable).

Comment: Other problems aside you should always use decimal for this kind of calculaton, not double!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you are calculating the `comission` yet also trying to parse it beforehand. When you attempt to parse it beforehand, it is reading the empty `txtComission` field and failing. I think you meant to switch the behavior, like so:

```
private void btnCalculateComission_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    double value = double.Parse(txtValue.Text);
    double percentage = 0.1;

    double comission = value * percentage;

    txtComission.Text = comission.ToString();
}
```

This calculates `comission` then assigns it to the correct field in your user interface.

Comment: The question about *parsing* a double with `double.Parse` (*`I still get the error "Input string was not in a correct format."`*), but your answer doesn't address it.

Comment: Thanks, this worked. I was just trying to parse it in the wrong place. I'll mark the answer once it lets me do it.

Comment: @IanGermann It is not related where you try to parse. It is about what you type to textboxes...

Comment: @L.B: Perhaps you misunderstand what was meant by the OP. He was parsing an empty field (`txtComission.Text`). Instead he meant to fill this field with a value. My answer does address this ("...trying to parse it beforehand."). The fact that it is now working for him demonstrates that my assumption was correct.

Comment: @grovesNL than you should have explained it in answer better, instead of just simply posting *how it should be*.

Comment: @L.B: I thought it was obvious based on that sentence. Regardless, I've added clarification.